# Good tool to test WCF service (not SOAP/HTTP webservice)

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, automated-tests, soapui

I recently found SOAPUI and discovered that it is just a great tool for testing any SOAP/HTTP service. Conventionally, we have been developing our own driver to test our services (WCF based netTCP binding) so far. But with SOAPUI experience, I am really looking for some such tool that can be used with such ease with built-in facilities for load testing, functional testing etc.

The other thought in my mind is that for services that I wish to deploy with netTCP can be first tested using a HTTP binding using SOAPUI. Once found suitable, the binding can be changed for the intended one.

I shall like the views from all the experts here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as standalone tools go, I have decent experience with [wcfstorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx) (commercial) and [wcfstorm LITE](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/wcfstorm-lite.aspx) (free)

But generally, when bindings allow, I just spin up the service in a [controlled server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/test-with-vs-devserver-2.aspx) and run NUnit tests against it.

Comment: Does it support bindings other than HTTP, like netTCP binding? It does not. It supports webservice on WCF. SOAPUI does the same and I feel SOAPUI is much better.

Comment: @kangkan - you are mistaken. look closer.

Answer (score 1):

I write automated unit tests to test the services. That way, I'm not dependent on a tool.